# Incorporating structural information in a Transformer?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, transformer, graph-neural-network

For a Neural Machine Translation (NMT) task, my input data has relational information. This relation could be modelled using a graphical structure.

So one approach could be to use Graph Neural Network (GNN) and use a Graph2Seq model. But I can't find a good generational model for GNN.

Instead, I want to use Transformer. But then the challenge is how can I embed structural information there? Is there any open source artefact for Relational Transformer that I can use out of the box?

Answer (score 0):

Some researchers have tried to exploit transformer for graph data. Please read this paper for more [details](https://arxiv.org/abs/2012.09699)

The implemented code for this has been outsourced on github [location](https://github.com/graphdeeplearning/graphtransformer) with an explanation on youtube [video](https://youtu.be/h-_HNeBmaaU?t=240)

Comment: do you know is there an implemented version of this?

Comment: Hi updated the details, hope it helps

Comment: The code does not work :-(